# Combining json_arrayagg and json_object with json_table always returns the first line

Tags: sql, json, database, oracle

The following source code doesn't return the expected values except when I remove the columns `v_f_1000` and `v_f_2`:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT v_f
  FROM json_table(R_P.json_data, '$[*]' columns (r_p_i NUMBER path '$.r_p_i', v_f path '$.v_f'))
  WHERE r_p_i = 1000
  ) AS "v_f_1000",
  (SELECT v_f
  FROM json_table(R_P.json_data, '$[*]' columns (r_p_i NUMBER path '$.r_p_i', v_f path '$.v_f'))
  WHERE r_p_i = 2
  ) AS "v_f_2",
  R_P.json_data,
  R_P.r_c,
  R_P.r_r
FROM
  (SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object(KEY 'r_p_i' value r_p_i, KEY 'v_f' value v_f, KEY 'u_i' value u_i ABSENT ON NULL)
  ORDER BY NULL) json_data,
    r_c,
    r_r
  FROM
    (SELECT '26658' AS r_c,
      '00'          AS r_r,
      1000          AS r_p_i,
      8.5           AS v_f,
      'MM'          AS u_i
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '26917' AS r_c,
      '00'         AS r_r,
      2            AS r_p_i,
      10           AS v_f,
      'R71'        AS u_i
    FROM dual
    )
  GROUP BY r_c,
    r_r
  ) R_P;
```

Actual result:

```
8.5   null  [{"r_p_i":1000,"v_f":8.5,"u_i":"MM"}]   26658   00
8.5   null  [{"r_p_i":1000,"v_f":8.5,"u_i":"MM"}]   26917   00
```

Expected result:

```
8.5   null  [{"r_p_i":1000,"v_f":8.5,"u_i":"MM"}]   26658   00 
null  10    [{"r_p_i":2,"v_f":10,"u_i":"R71"}]      26917   00
```

I use Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 and Oracle 19.0.0.0.0. I tried several optimizer hints without success, `NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION` produces an ORA-600 error. I think that it's a bug, `R_P.json_data` shouldn't be different when I add the columns `v_f_1000` and `v_f_2` into the select clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think that my first implementation above should work as expected (it will be reported as a bug) but replacing json_arrayagg by json_objectagg and json_table by json_value makes it work:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(R_P.json_data, '$."1000".v_f') AS "v_f_1000",
  JSON_VALUE(R_P.json_data, '$."2".v_f')         AS "v_f_2",
  R_P.json_data,
  R_P.r_c,
  R_P.r_r
FROM
  (SELECT json_objectagg(KEY TO_CHAR(r_p_i) value json_object(KEY 'v_f' value v_f, KEY 'u_i' value u_i ABSENT ON NULL)) AS json_data,
    r_c,
    r_r
  FROM
    (SELECT '26658' AS r_c,
      '00'          AS r_r,
      1000          AS r_p_i,
      8.5           AS v_f,
      'MM'          AS u_i
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '26917' AS r_c,
      '00'         AS r_r,
      2            AS r_p_i,
      10           AS v_f,
      'R71'        AS u_i
    FROM dual
    )
  GROUP BY r_c,
    r_r
  ) R_P;
```

**Important update**:
Calling `to_char()` on the JSON data when passing it to `json_table` seems to be enough to solve my problem:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT v_f
  FROM json_table(to_char(R_P.json_data), '$[*]' columns (r_p_i NUMBER path '$.r_p_i', v_f path '$.v_f'))
  WHERE r_p_i = 1000
  ) AS "v_f_1000",
  (SELECT v_f
  FROM json_table(to_char(R_P.json_data), '$[*]' columns (r_p_i NUMBER path '$.r_p_i', v_f path '$.v_f'))
  WHERE r_p_i = 2
  ) AS "v_f_2",
  R_P.json_data,
  R_P.r_c,
  R_P.r_r
FROM
  (SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object(KEY 'r_p_i' value r_p_i, KEY 'v_f' value v_f, KEY 'u_i' value u_i ABSENT ON NULL)
  ORDER BY NULL) json_data,
    r_c,
    r_r
  FROM
    (SELECT '26658' AS r_c,
      '00'          AS r_r,
      1000          AS r_p_i,
      8.5           AS v_f,
      'MM'          AS u_i
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '26917' AS r_c,
      '00'         AS r_r,
      2            AS r_p_i,
      10           AS v_f,
      'R71'        AS u_i
    FROM dual
    )
  GROUP BY r_c,
    r_r
  ) R_P;
```